# Repeatable Pseudorandom Sample of rows in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I want to randomly sample some subset of my data, using a random seed so that it will be repeatable.  Currently, I have this working minus the seed:

```
select * from my_table
where version is not null
  and start_datetime::date >= date('2020-03-16')
  and start_datetime::date < date('2020-05-15')
order by random()
limit 10000
```

Now I'd like to set a random seed so I can reliably get the same results from this query.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses [random function `setseed()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html). As explained in the documentation: once this function is called, *the results of subsequent `random()` calls in the current session are repeatable by re-issuing `setseed()` with the same argument*.

The technique is to include the call to the function directly in your query, using `union all`, and then sort in the outer query. This requires listing the columns that you want to return from the query. Assuming that you want columns `col1, col2, col3`, your query would be:

```
select * 
from (
    select setseed(0.5) colx, null col1, null col2, null col3
    union all
    select null, col1, col2, col3
    from mytable
    where 
        rpt.assist_detail.version is not null
        and start_datetime::date >= date '2020-03-16'
        and start_datetime::date <  date '2020-05-15'
    offset 1
) t
order by random()
limit 10000
```

`offset 1` is there to drop the row generated by the first subquery. The argument of `setseed()` (here `0.5`) may be any arbitrary value between `-1` and `1`. As long as you pass the same value, you get the same sort.

Answer (score -1):

`RANDOM()` is non-repeatable by definition.

If you want to get the same ordering based on a random value again, you have no choice but to store the random values, once obtained, somewhere.

I suggest you create your own table, adding an integer column, which you fill with a random integer:

```
CREATE TABLE my_random_ordered_sample AS
SELECT
  (RANDOM()*10000)::INT AS rand_ord
, *
FROM mytable
WHERE rpt.assist_detail.version IS NOT NULL
  AND start_datetime::DATE >= '2020-03-16'::DATE
  AND start_datetime::DATE <  '2020-05-15'::DATE
;
```

Once you have it, you can:

```
SELECT
  all_the
, columns_
, except_the
, ordering_column
, named_rand_ord
FROM my random_ordered_sample
ORDER BY rand_ord;
```